# Can I do this in JavaScript? Conditional return if arguments not passed

Tags: javascript, function, return, conditional-statements

I want to be able to pass this function either a number to return as a factorial or a number and an id for an existing element on the page, so that it can return the number as text inside my specified element. Here is my code:

```
function factorial(num,id){
    var f=1
    for (var i=2; i<=num; i++) {
        f*=i;
    }
    if (!id) {
        return f;
    }
    else if (id) 
        var msg= document.getElementById(id);
        return {
        msg.textContent = num + "! =  " + output;
        };
    }
}

factorial(5,"message");
```

Comment: What is `output`? Should be `f`, isn't it?

Comment: why not `return num + "! =  " + output;` where does `output` come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the element if passed *then* return unconditionally:

```
function factorial(num, id){
    var f = 1;
    for (var i=2; i<=num; i++) {
        f *= i;
    }

    if (id) {
        document.getElementById(id).textContent = num + "! =  " + f;
    }

    return f;
 }

alert(factorial(5));

alert(factorial(5,"message"));
```

Comment: Ahh I see what I was doing wrong. Plus I had used output without defining it. This works better.

Comment: Also for IE7/8 you need .innerText rather than .textContent.  In this case you can use .innerHTML which works in everything

Comment: Thank for the tip. I knew innerHTML was good all around but wasn't aware that ie 7/8 wouldn't work with .textContent. Thanks for the heads up!